# WorkFront API - How to create Project Request object

Tags: workfront-api

I am trying to use the WorkFront API. I got the API key created and am able to create a project with a name and status. However, what we need is creation of Project Request with request type being a drop down of one of the Request Queues. Does Workfront APIs support this. If so, can anyone provide guidance on this. I went through API Basics and API Explorer and do not see any objects for Project Request under API Explorer.

Comment: You need to be more clear with your requirements. Are you trying to submit an issue into an existing project's request queue?

Comment: @BrianR , trying to create a Request that will be converted to a project later with an API - https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000121794-Creating-and-Submitting-Workfront-Requests. This link shows how to create UI, I need to create similarly using API.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out later. A project request is nothing but an issue. We just needed to use the issue API to create the project request.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the exact scenario. I need to create a request which will later convert to project. When I do it from UI, I can see a call  "request/add " is going with the request data as form url encoded, but when I use this endpoint from postman, it fails with saying -> Title = null.

Comment: It has been more than 2 years since I used the APIs for a tactical project at that point. However, as far as I remember, you should look for the issue API. It should have all the fields that you need for creating the request - Title and others.

Comment: It's later resolved. It is related to the access of workfront application. Between, thanks for the response.